# Why doesn't my code read hex correctly?

Tags: ruby, irb

When I run the following code in IRB:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > x = %w(‎61 6C 6C 20 75 72 20 73 79 73 74 65 6D 73 20 62 65 6C 6F 6E 67 20 32 20 75 73)
1.9.3p194 :002 > puts x.map {|z| z.to_i(16)}.map(&:chr).join.inspect
```

I get:

```
"\x00ll ur systems belong 2 us"
=> nil
```

However `"61".to_i(16).chr` is `"a"`, not `"\x00"`.

What is going on there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you have an invisible Unicode [left-to-right mark,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark) located just after the `%w(`. It shows up encoded in UTF-8 by the time I see it via Stack Overflow, but it looks like it must have been (Windows?) UTF-16 in your original source.

Comment: Wow, that's kinda freaky, but pry shows it... To further illustrate: when I copy paste from the example, I get `x = %w(\U+FFE261 6C 6C 20 75 72 20 73 79 73 74 65 6D 73 20 62 65 6C 6F 6E 67 20 32 20 75 73)`